# String with several similar words has a higher score than string with exact match in Oracle fuzzy text search

Tags: oracle, text-search

When I run the following text search query in Oracle:

```
SELECT SCORE(1), text_search
FROM search  
WHERE contains(text_search, 'fuzzy(citi, 70, 100, WEIGHT) within Name', 1) > 0 
ORDER BY SCORE(1) DESC
```

returned records with the highest score of 100 are those which contain more than one similar words to 'citi':
**City** of Kansas **City** - score 100

But the records which contain the exact match have the score of only 76:
**Citi** Group - score 76

Records which contain only one similar word have the score of 53
**City** of Abilene - score 53

Shouldn't the records with the exact match have the highest score? Is there any way to achieve that?

If I increase `similarity_score` to 80, records with 'city' are not returned any more. But that reduces the number of returned records for other searches.

If I decrease `numterms` to 2, records with 'city' are not returned any more (apparently Oracle doesn't consider ‘city’ as the second most similar word for ‘citi’). But this again reduces the number of returned records for other searches.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Text is a vast product within the database (it earns two books in the documentation).  Text has  many knobs and levers we can use to modify the out-of-the-box behaviour.  It's hard to be sure what you're trying to achieve, but I think you should experiment with a query template, as that mechanism allows us to create user-defined scoring algorithms.  [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCAPP/query.htm#CCAPP9168).